# Add custom fields to Woocommerce Category Page

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy

I want to add custom fields to Category Woocommerce items (page-products-cat);
I have tried using this code but It does not work :

```
add_action(‘product_cat_edit_form_fields’, ‘wh_taxonomy_edit_meta_field’, 10, 1);

//Product Cat Edit page
function wh_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {

    //getting term ID
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field.
    $wh_meta_title = get_term_meta($term_id, ‘wh_meta_title’, true);
    $wh_meta_desc = get_term_meta($term_id, ‘wh_meta_desc’, true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="wh_meta_title"><?php _e(‘Meta Title’, ‘wh’); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="wh_meta_title" id="wh_meta_title" value="<?php echo esc_attr($wh_meta_title) ? esc_attr($wh_meta_title) : ”; ?>">
            <p class="description"><?php _e(‘Enter a meta title, <= 60 character’, ‘wh’); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="wh_meta_desc"><?php _e(‘Meta Description’, ‘wh’); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <textarea name="wh_meta_desc" id="wh_meta_desc"><?php echo esc_attr($wh_meta_desc) ? esc_attr($wh_meta_desc) : ”; ?></textarea>
            <p class="description"><?php _e(‘Enter a meta description’, ‘wh’); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Thanks in advance